# Rails route pointing to wrong place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In attempts to make my application more clean I have decided to create an imports controller and a views folder along with that instead of creating an `import.html.erb` view and an import method in my users controller.

My goal is to make the url: http://10.0.0.7/accounts/1/users/import

However, as one might think, this is directing to the show page and is thinking that import is the users id. How can I create the route so that it does not think that the word import is actually the users id?

Parameters shown in error page: `{"account_id"=>"1", "id"=>"import"}`

In my routes file I have this route which takes care of the

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :users do collection { post :import, :controller => "imports", :action => "users" } end
end
```

I have also tried this route.

```
resources :accounts do
  post :import, controller: 'imports', action: 'users'
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues I see here.

First, `@accounts` is nil. This is probably because it's in a partial, and you need to pass in variables into the partial.

`<%= render partial: 'admin_sidebar', accounts: @accounts %>`

And then use the variable `accounts` in the partial. Also, why is `users` in the URL? Your basic routing should have done this just fine.

I'd suggest a route like:

`post 'account_users/:id', to: 'imports#users', as 'account_users'`

This says - if a post request to URL `/account_users/#` send to `imports` controller and use the `users` method.